# Performance of a loop within a collection parent record

Tags: c#

I want to make my classes a bit smarter. So I am adding to a sub-list which is a child of `DocumentLines` and I have `Documents`. Consider them to be like `OrderHeader`,`OrderLines`. The reason why I call them documents was that I am using status to tell what type of order it is.

I want to have a property in my class that will get the current items in the child list and sum the cost up so I have a property I can bind to in my form.
Is below ok or could it become too exhaustive if I have to say 20 products on an order?

```
public List<DocumentLines> Items;
public decimal OrderTotal
{
    get
    {
        decimal price = 0.00m;
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            price += item.LinePrice;
        }                
        return price;
    }
}
```

Comment: 20 items is not that number you have to worry about in that `foreach` loop. Even 2000 items. (Unless you have a tight loop using that property, but that's not the case if you're talking about data bindings.)

Comment: The best way to tell if something is a performance problem is to test the code with many items and see if performance is poor. Note that LINQ provides many shortcut methods to using loops. For example, `return Items.Select(item => item.LinePrice).Sum();` would be sufficient for your property.

Comment: @HereticMonkey `return Items.Sum(i => i.LinePrice);` is even shorter.

Comment: @dymanoid sure, but this isn't [codegolf.se] ;).

Comment: @HereticMonkey, sure it isn't, but then the OP's loop is OK too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be too exhaustive. It will be fine. You could consider using the LINQ [`Sum()` method](http://www.csharp-examples.net/linq-sum/).

```cs
public List<DocumentLines> Items;
public decimal OrderTotal
{
  get
  {
    return Items.Sum(item => item.LinePrice);
  }
}
```

With C# 6 you can use [expression-bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#read-only-properties) (=>) to shorten it further.

```cs
public List<DocumentLines> Items;
public decimal OrderTotal => Items.Sum(item => item.LinePrice);
```